# How to perform a statistic analysis by groups of 20 rows?

Tags: r

I have a matrix which contains 1000 rows and 40 columns and I want to do a basic statistical analysis (mean, sd, min and max) for every 20 rows. So in total there will be 50 sets of statistical results. I am using the “by” function:

```
library(vtable)

df<- read.csv(...)

idx <- ceiling((1:nrow(df))/20)
valuesm <- by(df, idx, function(x){sumtable(data= df, out='return',title='', summ=c('notNA(x)', 'mean(x)', 'sd(x)', 'min(x)', 'max(x)'))})
```

I have used the “by” function successfully before, however in this case I have not been able to make it work.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `by()` as `sumtable` uses it's own grouping parameter:

```
df$idx <- ceiling((1:nrow(df))/20)
sumtable(df, out='return', group = 'idx', title='', summ=c('notNA(x)', 'mean(x)', 'sd(x)', 'min(x)', 'max(x)'))
```